error closing the connection to the SQL database due to a query in Qt6/C++
my code outputs the error

QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'createRequestConnection' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.

although there is not even a QSqlQuery query, I can't figure out what the problem is all day, I'm sorry if the code doesn't look good, I'm just learning
here's what the code looks like
CreateRequestWindow.h
#ifndef CREATEREQUESTWINDOW_H
#define CREATEREQUESTWINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QString>
#include <QSqlDatabase>



QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui {
class CreateRequestWindow;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class CreateRequestWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CreateRequestWindow(const QString& login, QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~CreateRequestWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_close_clicked();
    void on_pushButton_create_clicked();

signals:
    void windowClosed();

private:
    QString userLogin;
    Ui::CreateRequestWindow* ui;
    QSqlDatabase db;
    void openDatabaseConnection();
};

#endif // CREATEREQUESTWINDOW_H

CreateRequestWindow.cpp
#include "createrequestwindow.h"
#include "ui_createrequestwindow.h"
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QDateTime>

CreateRequestWindow::CreateRequestWindow(const QString& login, QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , userLogin(login)
    , ui(new Ui::CreateRequestWindow)
{
    openDatabaseConnection();
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

CreateRequestWindow::~CreateRequestWindow(){
    db.close();
    QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("createRequestConnection");
    delete ui;
}

void CreateRequestWindow::on_pushButton_close_clicked()
{
    this->close();
}

void CreateRequestWindow::on_pushButton_create_clicked()
{



    emit windowClosed();
}

void CreateRequestWindow::openDatabaseConnection(){
    if (!QSqlDatabase::contains("createRequestConnection")) {
        db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC", "createRequestConnection");
        db.setDatabaseName("zxctatar");
        if(!db.open()){
            qDebug() << "Failed open database CreateRequestWindow\n";
            return;
        }
    } else {
        db = QSqlDatabase::database("createRequestConnection");
    }
}

ClientWindow.h
#ifndef CLIENTWINDOW_H
#define CLIENTWINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <createrequestwindow.h>
#include <QSqlDatabase>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui {
class ClientWindow;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class ClientWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ClientWindow(const QString& userLogin, QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~ClientWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_close_clicked();
    void on_pushButton_createRequest_clicked();
    void updateWindow();
    void closeCreateRequestWindow(CreateRequestWindow* createRequestWindow);

private:
    QString userLogin;
    Ui::ClientWindow *ui;
    void showRequests(const QString& userLogin);
    void openDatabaseConnection();
    QSqlDatabase db;
};

#endif // CLIENTWINDOW_H

ClientWindow.cpp(where there is interaction with CreateRequestWindow)
void ClientWindow::on_pushButton_createRequest_clicked()
{
    CreateRequestWindow* createRequestWindow = new CreateRequestWindow(userLogin);
    createRequestWindow->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    createRequestWindow->show();
    connect(createRequestWindow, &CreateRequestWindow::windowClosed, this, [=](){
        closeCreateRequestWindow(createRequestWindow);
    });

    
    connect(createRequestWindow, &QObject::destroyed, this, [=](){
    disconnect(createRequestWindow, &CreateRequestWindow::windowClosed, this, nullptr);
    });
}

void ClientWindow::closeCreateRequestWindow(CreateRequestWindow* createRequestWindow){
    createRequestWindow->close();
}


QSqlDatabase db; - this is the existing instance. As the documentation tells you, don't store QSqlDatabase database instances as you might encounter errors like this.

and then how do I pass the QSqlDatabase object to the method? or should I create a connection in the method itself where the QSqlQuery query occurs?

Simply pass it to the method (e.g. as reference) - the only thing the doc is telling you is that you should not store it as member.
